# What is the reason that I am getting unknown characters as response?

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

Probably I am might bemissing something, but I do not understand why am I getting some random characters in the function response like â‰¥,â‰¤? I have checked it against the database too there also these characters are present

Below is the sample response

`test is required by local laboratory testing.), with at least one of the following\r\n            conditions: (1) histological grade III; (2) Ki67 â‰¥ 30%; (3) progesterone receptor (PR)\r\n            â‰¤ 20% positive;`

how should I decode the above string in C#?

Comment: please share some code to enable other users to help you

Comment: I am receiving the response straight as function response  how should I decode the above string in C#?

Comment: We need a lot more detail of the code calling the function and what the function actually is that's returning these characters.

Comment: In db the response is also saved in the same format. 

Fuction is being called as
 OperationResult<StudyModel> result = await ExecuteFunction("GetDetails", request);

Comment: This is a flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'â‰¥,â‰¤'.encode( 'cp1252').decode('utf-8')` returns `'≥,≤'` and vice versa: `'≥,≤'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'â‰¥,â‰¤'` (example given in Python as it's self-explanatory).